# sum over multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I have a table with N columns.

I would like to have the sum of each single columns:

```
 SELECT
    id
,   SUM(X1) as X1
,   SUM(X2) as X2
,   SUM(X3) as X3
............
FROM test
```

However I would prefer not to list all the columns because I have too many of them.

Is there is a way to make an overall sum for each column in SQL Server?

Comment: Sounds like maybe having that many columns isn't the best approach. You could have one row per value type(X1, X2, X3) and then get what you need by `SELECT SUM(value) FROM test GROUP BY type`

Comment: Not in standard SQL - it's _possible_ that some provider has a syntax for this but none that I know of.  You could code-gen it or just bite the bullet and type them out - it probably would take less time than it took to write the question and sift through the answers.

Comment: simply put,you can't do this..You can' use dynamic sql,but it can be complex

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with SQL Server:

setting up a test schema

```
create table p (id int, x1 int, x2 int, x3 int);

insert into p values
(1,1,0,1),
(2,1,1,0),
(3,1,0,1),
(1,1,1,1);
```

now the SQL

```
declare @stmt as nvarchar(600);

set @stmt =     
(
select concat('select id,',    (
      SELECT LEFT(column_names , LEN(column_names )-1) AS column_names
    FROM information_schema.columns AS extern
    CROSS APPLY
    (
    SELECT concat('sum(',column_name , ') as ', column_name,',')
    FROM information_schema.columns AS intern
    WHERE extern.table_name = intern.table_name and column_name <> 'ID'
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ) pre_trimmed (column_names)
    where table_name = 'p' 
    GROUP BY table_name, column_names
    ),
    ' from p group by id')
    );


execute sp_executesql @stmt;
```

If you add a hundred other columns it should work.

You basically build a SQL Query string and then execute it.

The key here is that I am assuming that you have an `ID` column and then all `Xn` columns.  So if you had another ref column, say name, that you didn't wan't summed you would change your `Information_Schema` query to 'and `column_name not in ('id','name')` etc.

If this is also Onerous, you could add a where clause in the inner select to only sum columns with Type Int.

[Here is a working example](http://rextester.com/TSL12450)

Answer (score 0):

are you asking for this

```
x1  x2   x3
2    3    4
2    3    4

4    6     8  --result
```

then try this code

```
   SELECT 
   SUM(salary) as 'X1',
   SUM(age) as 'X2',
   SUM(mark) as 'X3'
   FROM tsum
```